# Laravel if condition not working in template?

Tags: laravel

I am passing some data in Laravel template. I am using if condition in template but my else part is not working my condition is `@if($portfolio->active) class="label label-success" @else class="label label-danger" @endif`. I checked `{{$portfolio->active}}` but it has value **0** so my else part should be run but always `if` part is running my `else` part is not working

Comment: What does `dd($portfolio->active)` show?

Comment: it shows 0 my else part shout be run but my if part is running

Comment: what will happen if you try to explicitly define your if condition like `@if($portfolio->active != '0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in your Portfolio model:

```
    protected $casts = ['active' => 'boolean'];
```

This will make the 'active' field into a boolean. Then you can write your if else as:

```
    @if($portfolio->active)
    @else
    @endif
```

This will make your code a little bit more readable. You can avoid the else by doing the converse like:

```
@if(!portfolio->active)
//your else code here
@endif
//your if code here
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@if($portfolio->active ==0)

@else

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use in this way

```
class="{{ ($portfolio->active) ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger' }}
```